# Turning a command line app into a Cocoa GUI app on Mac OS X?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, command-line

Is there any tutorials or references, if such thing is possible, to make GUI applications out of command line apps?
What I mean is, having a command line app, wrap it into an app bundle and create a Cocoa GUI app that would have a simple interface to execute the command line app with its flags and parameters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As a matter of fact there are.  Here is the first hit for a Google search:

- [Cocoa Dev Central: Wrapping UNIX Commands](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000025.php)

What you're looking for is the `NSTask` class.  Check out the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTask_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for all the information you need.

Answer (score 5):

For very simple scripts, I recommend [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus). For more complicated scenarios, you could try something like [Pashua](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/pashua/).

Comment: Platypus is great.  It outputs the results in a WebView or Text Window, shows a progress bar, and can have a status menu..  You can also set environmental variables, arguments, even the Icon.  It's rad.