# Turning XCode command line C++ program into a Cocoa Mac App OSX program

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

So I have a program that I have been developing for a while (for fun) on XCode written in C++ as a command line tool program. However I just recently had the idea to turn it into a Mac OSX application. The idea would be to use cocoa/objective-c to create the UI and keep the C++ backend. However, I don't know how to add this in to a project that has already been created as a command line program. Would I have to create a brand new project as a cocoa application and copy/paste my existing code over? Or is there a simpler way to achieve what it is I'm looking to do?

Comment: not an exact duplicate, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134035/turning-a-command-line-app-into-a-cocoa-gui-app-on-mac-os-x?rq=1) is similar and may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

A project can contain multiple targets.  You can probably do what you want by creating a target that matches the app type you want and then adding existing files as necessary to that target.