# Can a Swift Console App have an app Icon?

Tags: xcode, icons, swift

I seriously looked around on the Apple developer site and SO for this, but I couldn't find an answer.

I created a small console app in Xcode 6.4 and I want to change the app icon. Is this possible for console apps?

Thanks for replies!

David

Comment: What do you mean? A console app doesn't appear in the Dock. It would usually reside in e.g. `/usr/bin` or somewhere that nobody will ever see it in Finder.

Comment: Hmm.. I am really new at programming in XCode and this is my first app. I compiled the swift-code, created a build and now I have this nice executable on my desktop which actually boots a console...

Comment: You might want to look into Platypus, or wrap your console app yourself in an NSTask from a "proper" windowed app. Either way, you'd be able to set up an icon. [More info in this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3134035/turning-a-command-line-app-into-a-cocoa-gui-app-on-mac-os-x); this isn't Swift-specific.